# Trouble running Warp, on WAI, in Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, haskell-warp, haskell-wai

I've written a simple Hello World application for (Warp) on (Wai). It works fine in Ubuntu Linux, as do more complicated apps. But I can't even get this Hello World app to run in Windows. I'm using Haskell Platform (installation file 2012.2.0.0) on Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 32-bit.

This is the code (which works in Linux):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-} 

import Network
import Network.Wai
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
application = \_-> return $ responseLBS status200 [("Content-Type", "text/plain")] 
                            "Hello World" 

main = withSocketsDo $ do run 3000 application
```

These are the GHCI messages upon loading the code, and running (main):

```
Prelude> :l wai_hello_world.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( wai_hello_world.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> main
Loading package bytestring-0.9.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package [ **edited**: blah blah blah - other packages - removed for readability]
Loading package warp-1.3.2 ... linking ... done.
```

After loading the code, the web server does not appear to be running.

I think I might be running into some common gotcha - if so please let me know.

Thanks in advance  for all feedback.

> (***Update***: as noted in an answer below, these errors are solely due to the Ctrl-C action, killing the runtime, and not part of the unexpected behaviour of Wai/Warp in the question.)
>
> If I hit Ctrl-C a few times to break out, I get these messages, or
>   some variety of them:
>
> ```
> NIenttweorrrku.pStoecdk.e
> t.ace*Main> p: failed (No error)
> user error (accept: can't perform accept on socket ((AF_INET,Stream,0)) in status Closed)
> user error (accept: can't perform accept on socket ((AF_INET,Stream,0)) in status Closed)
> *Main>
> *Main> user error (accept: can't perform accept on socket ((AF_INE,:Sream,0)) in status Closed)
> q
> Leaving GHCi.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use [`withSocketsDo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/2.4.0.1/doc/html/Network.html#v%3awithSocketsDo).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this does not change the misbehaviour of the program. I have updated the original post to include `withSocketsDo $do`.

Comment: Then I'm not certain. The error messages are certainly being caused by the call to Ctrl-C, but I don't know why the code didn't work in the first place. On my Windows XP virtual machine, it loads up correctly. Maybe there was a firewall issue?

Comment: Reinstalled: Haskell Platform 2012.4.0.0, with libraries from a standard (cabal install yesod-platform), I now have no problem. Perhaps it was the firewall. :-S

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the problem (and I do feel silly):

1. Tore down the stack, uninstalled Haskell Platform 2012.2.0.0 for Windows.
2. Installed the latest Haskell Platform 2012.4.0.0 for Windows.
3. Installed the package/libraries (cabal install yesod-platform).
4. Approved the Windows Firewall query on GHC, when the code was run.
5. Code now runs as expected. I now have no problem. Perhaps it was the firewall. :-S